# Marker exibe infoWindow errado

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google

Estou utilizando a API do Google Maps para criar Markers em endereços que informo no arquivo `js`. Junto a essa API também tem o `autocomplete` do Google, para completar o endereço que estou digitando no `input`. O script está funcionando perfeitamente, tirando o fato de se eu colocar o endereço da minha casa por exemplo e clicar no `marker` que está em cima do meu endereço, ele puxa as últimas informações da variavel **markers** que contém os endereços. Ele puxa as informações do endereço de **valinhos** .. Teste o script direto no site http://www.brasilpark.com.br/unidades . Coloque o endereço da sua casa por exemplo, para entender o que estou falando. Abaixo o código `js` que estou utilizando:

**mapa.js**

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

var markers = [{"Estado":"Goiás","Cidade":"Goiânia","Bairro":"Jardim Goiás","Unidade":"CARREFOUR GOIÂNIA SUL","Endereco":"Avenida Deputado Jamel Cecílio, 3900 - Jardim Goías - Goiânia - GO","Lat":"-16.7093680","Lng":"-49.2325750"},{"Estado":"São Paulo","Cidade":"Valinhos","Bairro":"Jardim Maracanã","Unidade":"HOSPITAL E MATERNIDADE GALILEO","Endereco":"Av. Dr. Alfredo Zacarias, 1816 “ Jardim Maracanã - Valinhos “ SP","Lat":-23.0008593,"Lng":-46.99138019999999}]; //Tem vários endereços aqui

function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.5557040,-46.6627530);
    var options = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), options);

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        draggable: true
    });

    marker.setPosition(latlng);

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

       for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].Lat, markers[i].Lng);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i].Unidade
        });

        // Allow each marker to have an info window
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent('<h1>'+markers[i].Unidade+'</h1>'+'<br /><br />'+markers[i].Endereco);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }




}

$(document).ready(function () {

    initialize();

    function carregarNoMapa(endereco) {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': endereco + ', Brasil', 'region': 'BR' }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                    $('#txtEndereco').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                    $('#txtLatitude').val(latitude);
                    $('#txtLongitude').val(longitude);

                    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    marker.setPosition(location);
                    map.setCenter(location);
                    map.setZoom(16);
                }
            }
        })
    }

    $("#btnEndereco").click(function() {
        if($(this).val() != "")
            carregarNoMapa($("#txtEndereco").val());
    })

    $("#txtEndereco").blur(function() {
        if($(this).val() != "")
            carregarNoMapa($(this).val());
    })

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function () {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': marker.getPosition() }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    $('#txtEndereco').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                    $('#txtLatitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                    $('#txtLongitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $("#txtEndereco").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': request.term + ', Brasil', 'region': 'BR' }, function (results, status) {
                response($.map(results, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.formatted_address,
                        value: item.formatted_address,
                        latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
                        longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
                    }
                }));
            })
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#txtLatitude").val(ui.item.latitude);
            $("#txtLongitude").val(ui.item.longitude);
            var location = new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude);
            marker.setPosition(location);
            map.setCenter(location);
            map.setZoom(16);
        }
    });

    $("form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var endereco = $("#txtEndereco").val();
        var latitude = $("#txtLatitude").val();
        var longitude = $("#txtLongitude").val();

        alert("Endereço: " + endereco + "\nLatitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude);
    });

});
```